# Обнаружение файлов в папке

Tags: java

Допустим у меня есть программа проходящая по всему тексту. Текст подкрепплен к проекту файлом .txt, но мне надо что бы данная программа проходила не один текст а кучу различных. Можно ли создать допустим папку в которой будет куча различных текстов формата pdf или еще какого и что бы прога понимала что там появились новые тексты и их тоже считывала? Подскажите как такое реализовать и как лучше сделать.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы хотите получать уведомления об изменении файлов в какой-то папке, то вы можете воспользоваться [WatchService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchService.html) ([туториал](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html)).

Если вы хотите дать возможность пользователю выбрать несколько файлов для обработки, то вы можете воспользоваться [FileDialog](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/FileDialog.html) или [JFileChooser](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html) в режиме выбора нескольких файлов.

Для чтения PDF есть несколько библиотек, выбирайте на свой вкус. То же касается и остальных форматов файлов.